# How to generate a slug everytime an article is created and saved in the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, slug

So, I have this **articleSchema** in which I want to create a unique slug.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
var URLSlug = require('mongoose-slug-generator')

const articleSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    slug: { type: "String", slug: "title", unique: true }
}, { timestamps: true })


articleSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    this.slug = this.title.split(" ").join("-")
    next()
})

articleSchema.plugin(URLSlug("title", {field: "Slug"}))

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema)

module.exports = Article
```

Here is the **articleController**

```
    newArticle: (req, res) => {
        Article.create(req.body, (err, newArticle) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(404).json({ error: "No article found" })
            } else {
                return res.status(200).json({ article: newArticle })
            }
        })
    }
```

I don't know, when I check this in postman it's saying no article found, let alone the slug! Also, I'm getting this error:

`schema.eachPath is not a function`

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome, can you please mark my answer as answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Slug is generated but it's like ```"slug": "metal-head-dev-XLyKR3pH"```.

Comment: What did you send as request body?

Comment: The same as you sent. I tried with and without user_id. But the slug was same.

Comment: Did you replaced all your schema code as in my answer?  I tried this and it is working correcty.

Comment: Yes, I replaced all your code, still, the slug is the same. Idk why it's appending some random text at the end of the slug.

Comment: Can you try like this?  remove the unique option in slug field in the schema. Drop the articles collection (if needed backup collection), and try?

Comment: Oh, I get it now. It's generating a text at the end to make the slug unique. Thanks, mate, appreciate your help.

Comment: Great, please don't forget to mark as asnwer as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [mongoose-slug-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-slug-generator) you need to apply plugin on mongoose, but in your code it is applied to the schema.

So if you try with this code, it will work:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var URLSlug = require("mongoose-slug-generator");

mongoose.plugin(URLSlug);

const articleSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    slug: { type: String, slug: "title"}
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

articleSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  this.slug = this.title.split(" ").join("-");
  next();
});

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

module.exports = Article;
```

If we send a req.body like this:

```
{
    "title": "metal head dev",
    "userId": "5e20954dc6e29d1b182761c9",
    "description": "description"
}
```

The saved document will be like this (as you see slug is generated correctly):

```
{
    "_id": "5e23378672f10f0dc01cae39",
    "title": "metal head dev",
    "description": "description",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-18T16:51:18.445Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-18T16:51:18.445Z",
    "slug": "metal-head-dev",
    "__v": 0
}
```

By the way `mongoose-slug-generator` seems pretty old, there is a more popular and well maintained [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) package.

Comment: Can you please tell me how would you handle two similar titles when using `slugify`?

Comment: `mongoose-slug-generator` and `slugify` are not the same. `slugify` only generates an SEO-friendly URL from a string. while `mongoose-slug-generator` does the same in addition to handling storing the slug in the database with avoiding duplicates.

In fact, `mongoose-slug-generator` uses a package called `speakingurl` which is pretty much the same as `slugify`.